# PHP fetch data where in array using SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some comma-separated records that I am saving in a MySQL database.

I have the following table and records:

```
tbl_checks

id  | items
----+------
1   | 2,5
2   | 2,3
```

So I would like to fetch data where one of the comma-separated values in the column `items` is 5.

I have tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_checks WHERE items="; //unable todo at here
```

so that I can:

```
$results = $this->db->query($sql)->result() //codeigniter script
```

I have also tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_checks WHERE items=".in_array(5)//this fails
```

Comment: Storing data as comma separated items is not really the SQL way. Check out normalization.

Comment: Does that mean its 2,5 or value 2 and value 5

Comment: @Tomm value 2 and value 5

Comment: you can also use simple `IN` method to achieve this i guess

Comment: @Tomm i mean the sql statement should fetch the row having name as a value 5. that is i expect it to return only the first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach isn't that good, if you want to query against this field.  Normally, you would use normalization and split that data into multiple tables which could queried better.

If you have stuck with this approach, you could use `LIKE` and `CONCAT`.

```
$id = '2';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_checks WHERE CONCAT(',', items, ',') LIKE '%,$id,%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

$value = 5;

$result = $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET($value,items) !=", 0)
          ->get("tbl_checks")->result_array();

Answer (score -1):

I'm agree that such database isn't good constructed. Any way this query should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_checks 
WHERE ( items LIKE "5,%" ) 
OR (item LIKE "%,5");
```

Comment: this will only work, if the id is the first or last entry of items

Comment: Yes, it is truth, but by looking of two rows of sample data I think that this is format of data - the column is consists of pairs, comma separated. If there is possible the 3 values or much it has to be added to query ... OR ( item LIKE "%,5,%" )